# Hibernate Named Query is Null

Tags: hibernate, named-query

I have a problem with the hibernate named queries.

My Entity:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQueries;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQuery;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "getAllPersons", query = "select * from person p") })
@Entity
public class Person extends Party { .... }
```

My DAO:

```
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class DefaultPersonDao implements PersonDao{

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Person> getAllPersons() {
        Query query = getSession().getNamedQuery("getAllPersons");
        List<Person> persons = query.list();
        return persons;
    }
}
```

I always get a NullPointerException when I do `query.list()`, because the query I get from the sessionfactory is null.

(`getSession()` returns a `import org.hibernate.SessionFactory`)

Does anyone see the mistake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the logs, you must have an error logged somewhere, because the query is invalid. `select *` is a SQL query, not a JPQL (or HQL) one. It should be `select p from Person p`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using **HQL** if yes then there is a mistake in the syntax.use as below,
`query = "select p from Person p"`.

Comment: @juankysmith: except for person which should be Person, the query of ManuPK is valid HQL. select * is SQL, not HQL.

Comment: @juankysmith yes it is. You can try it. In-fact your answer is wrong **select * from person** is not a valid **HQL**. check the other answer also by **JB Nizet**. Try it before you **vote down** :).